# Azure DevOps Changing a Work Item from Feature to Backlog Item

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I hope that someone can help please.

I have a "Feature" Work Item Type that I want to appear in my project task board for the Sprint.  However, Features do not appear in a task board, only Backlog Items and Tasks.

I change the Work Item Type of the Feature to Backlog Item.  However, it still won't appear on the task board.  I have tried this a couple of ways (i.e. change type, move to...). No difference.  The only way is to create the item from scratch, which I want to avoid!  Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Check Area in your new Backlog Items that you create in the backlog and set the same value into your problem work item.

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer triggered what I needed to do.  The Area was not selected for the Team.  All solved